# How to expose postgres tcp port using Docker Desktop for Windows Kubernetes and ingress-nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm using "Docker Desktop for Windows" with kubernetes.  So far, its great.

I'd like to manage my postgress db (TCP:5432).  I'm using the kubernetes "ingress-nginx" ingress controller, which saws it can be [configured to expose TCP using a configmap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/exposing-tcp-udp-services/).

Here is what I have so far:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: tcp-services
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  5432: "ingress-nginx/postgres:5432"

---
# SEE: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-myproject.com
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: clusterissuer-selfsigned
    # See: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/from-to-www-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - www.myproject.com
    secretName: tls-myproject
  rules:
  # Avoid Quasar build paths:  /css, /fonts, /icons, /js
  - http:
      paths:
        # See https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/examples/rewrite/README.md
      - path: /data(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 80
...
```

Now I need to:

1. add the "--tcp-services-configmap=" argument
2. expose 5432 if 1) doesn't do this automatically.

I found the ingress-nginx-controller in the kubernetes dashboard and hand edited like below, but it's behavior didn't change.

```
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
      app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
        app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: webhook-cert
          secret:
            secretName: ingress-nginx-admission
            defaultMode: 420
      containers:
        - name: controller
          image: >-
            k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.41.0@sha256:e6019e536cfb921afb99408d5292fa88b017c49dd29d05fc8dbc456aa770d590
          args:
            - /nginx-ingress-controller
            - '--publish-service=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller'
            - '--election-id=ingress-controller-leader'
            - '--ingress-class=nginx'
            - '--configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/ingress-nginx-controller'
            - '--validating-webhook=:8443'
            - '--validating-webhook-certificate=/usr/local/certificates/cert'
            - '--validating-webhook-key=/usr/local/certificates/key'
            - '--tcp-services-configmap=ingress-nginx/tcp-services'
```

What am I missing?  How can I configure this w/o having to hand edit it?  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are 2 issues.

1. You need to install nginx separately from your postgress installation. This means that you will have some nginx pods/deployments, and a service that exist in the ingress-nginx namespace. To do this, follow the guide [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy). It is recommended that you follow a yaml file from the cloud section for a docker desktop deployment. [This](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/7094) is someone who has gone through the process.
2. Once nginx is installed on your cluster, you need to go from you postgress deployment/pod -> service -> ingress.  These will be in a different namespace than your ingress-nginx one (default is fine). To configure it, you can follow the guide located [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/basic-usage/). If you want to test things along the way, you can use kubernetes `port-forward`ing command to forward your postgress pod to your local machine. You can also test your service with the same method.

Comment: I think a port forward is probably the simplest thing that could work.  Thanks!